# Angular - setTimeout() function inside forEach() is ignored

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on the frontend of a Web Application with Angular. I have to save some data from an array in a database, by calling an API repeatedly until the data from the array are finished. I added the `setTimeout()` that you find below because I need the API to finish the work on an item of the array, before calling it again. However, it seems that the `setTimeout()` is completely ignored, and I don't understand why. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you in advance!

```
this.userEntitiesRoles.forEach(newRole => {
            this.user.entity = newRole.entity;
            this.user.role = newRole.role;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.usersService.addUser(this.user, this.lang).subscribe({
                next: (): void => {},
                error: (err): void => {
                  if(err.status != 401) {
                    var displayMessage = this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR').toUpperCase().concat(' \r\n').concat(err.message);
                    this.notify.error(displayMessage);
                  }
                }
              });
            }, 1000);
});
```

```
addUser(user: IUser, lang: string): Observable<IUser> {
    let payload = new FormData();
    payload.append('emailID', `${user.email}`);
    return this.http.post<IUser>(`${environment.SERVER_ROOT}/add?lang=${lang}`, payload)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Comment: can you please edit question and also share the handleError() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, using `setTimeout()` within a loop does not cause the calls to be executed sequentially.

It's essentially equivalent to this:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('#1'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('#2'), 1000);
setTimeout(() => console.log('#3'), 1000);
```

Which will basically, wait 1000ms then execute all three statements.

You *could*, attempt to nest them something like this:

```
setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log('#1'); 
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('#2');
        setTimeout(() => console.log('#3'), 1000);        
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

But this is really ugly.

The way you are going about it, you are attempting to enforce a `1000ms` delay all the time.  Even when the api call finishes sooner (*causing unnecessary waiting*) and even when the api takes longer than that (*meaning it wasn't finished before your next call is made*).

What you probably want to do, is have the calls fire consecutively, one after another as soon as they have finished.

We can use [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) for this.

```js
    // create array of observable calls to 'addUser'
    const roleUpdates = this.userEntitiesRoles.map(
      ({entity, role}) => this.usersService.addUser({ ...this.user, entity, role }, this.lang)
    );

    concat(...roleUpdates).subscribe({
      next: (): void => {},
      error: err => {
        if(err.status != 401) {
          const displayMessage = this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR').toUpperCase().concat(' \r\n').concat(err.message);
          this.notify.error(displayMessage);
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is being ignored because you are subscribing to an observable inside the setTimeout

Use promises. Make your userService function for adding a user return a promise

```
addUser(user: IUser, lang: string): Promise<IUser> {
   let payload = new FormData();
    payload.append('emailID', `${user.email}`);
    return this.http.post<IUser>(`${environment.SERVER_ROOT}/add?lang=${lang}`)
    .toPromise()

}
```

then use async await to make sure each user add operation completes

```
this.userEntitiesRoles.forEach(async newRole => {
     this.user.entity = newRole.entity;
     this.user.role = newRole.role;
     await this.usersService.addUser(this.user, this.lang)
});
```

Additionally you can wrap your code inside a try catch block  for error handling

```
this.userEntitiesRoles.forEach(async newRole => {
     this.user.entity = newRole.entity;
     this.user.role = newRole.role;
     try{
        await this.usersService.addUser(this.user, this.lang)
     }catch(err) {
         if(err.status != 401) {
            var displayMessage = this.translate.instant('ERRORS.GENERAL_ERROR').toUpperCase().concat(' \r\n').concat(err.message);
            this.notify.error(displayMessage);
          }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's even a better way, using rxjs `concat`. Create an array of requests and subscribe to them at once, `concat` will ensure that they are executed in sequence and only after previous request is finished. Using timeout might be buggy, especially when the connection is slower and 1 second is not enough.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

const requests = [];
this.userEntitiesRoles.forEach(newRole => {
  requests.push(this.usersService.addUser(newRole.entity, newRole.role));
});

concat(requests).subscribe(
  res => {//...}, 
  err => {//..}
);
```

Here you can find more information about it [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat)